# Please explain a python zip and unpacking solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

A Python 3 learner here:

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479319/possible-to-return-two-lists-from-a-list-comprehension) had the following accepted answer:

```
rr,tt = zip(*[(i*10, i*12) for i in xrange(4)])
```

which returns two tuples. I'd be grateful if someone could break down the answer and explain what it is doing with Python 3 in mind ( I know the `range()` returns an iterator in Python 3). I understand list comprehensions but I'm confused about unpacking (I thought you could only used a starred expression as part of an assignment target).

I'm equally confused by the code below. I understand the outcome and zipping (or think I do) but again the asterisk expression has got me beat.

```
x2, y2 = zip(*zip(x, y))
```

from [this](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> list(zipped)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> x2, y2 = zip(*zip(x, y))
>>> x == list(x2) and y == list(y2)
True
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*expression` applies [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) to the function call. It takes the `expression` part, which *has* to resolve to a iterable, and makes each element in that iterable a separate parameter to the function.

So, `zip(x, y)` returns an iterator (which is an iterable), and each element in that iterator is made an argument to the *outer* `zip()` function.

For `zip(*[(i*10, i*12) for i in xrange(4)])` it is perhaps a little clearer; there are several elements here:

- `[(i*10, i*12) for i in xrange(4)]` *(should be `range()` in python 3)* creates a list with 4 tuples, `[(0, 0), (10, 12), (20, 24), (30, 36)]`
- The `zip(*...)` part then takes each of those 4 tuples and passes those as arguments to the `zip()` function.
- `zip()` takes each tuple and pairs their elements; two elements per tuple means the result is 2 lists of 4 values each.

Because the `zip()` function produces two sequences, they can be assigned to the two variables.

I would have found the following a far more readable version of the same expression:

```
rr, tt = tuple(range(0, 40, 10)), tuple(range(0, 48, 12))
```