# How to return 2 lists from 2 lists using List Comprehension syntax?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

to all,
I was doing some searches on the use of list comprehension syntax. I would like to see if it's possible to return 2 lists from 2 existing lists with 1 line of code i.e using list comprehension. I came across this post
[Possible to return two lists from a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479319/possible-to-return-two-lists-from-a-list-comprehension) which make me think it's possible. Creating  the new lists independently works fine I would like to see how far I can take it i.e minimal code but still easily readable

Consider the following I have 2 pre-existing lists wnv and wdv and would like to create 2 new lists Av and Bv as follows;

```
Av,Bv=[(zeta*wn*dt,wd*dt) for i,(wn,wd) in zip(wnv,wdv)]
```

where zeta and dt are just a numbers
Can this be done? With the above code, I am getting the error: unpack non-iterable float object

Comment: Can you show the structure of `wnv`, `wdv` and how you're doing it without list comprehension?

Comment: Are both lists of the same length?  What would you like to happen if the lists are of different lengths?

Comment: Isn't the link that you shared wholly answer your question?

Comment: 1. Now that I see the addition of the zip() at the beginning of the line the link make sense. 2. The lists will always be the same length as they "emanate" from 1 list. 3. I had For ... loop on the "master" list in in which I calculate a number of variables on the fly, then I tested 1 line of code using list comprehension approach per list desired and finally realised that maybe I could create some of the lists using 1 line of code. I have no tested if the "1-line" approach is actually faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, you just have to unzip the result at the end :

```
Av,Bv = zip(*[(zeta*wn*dt,wd*dt) for (wn,wd) in zip(wnv,wdv)])
```

(and remove the `i` from your code)

Answer (score 0):

The error shows up as the zip creates a list of Tuples (each having 2 elements) which is iterated over. Here, only the tuple (wn, wd) is taken from the list that is being iterated and not the variable i.

The following code should work well:

> `Av,Bv = zip(*[(zeta*wn*dt,wd*dt) for (wn,wd) in zip(wnv,wdv)])`

PS, note that the end results Av and Bv are actually tuples and not lists.

Comment: The data in Av and Bv are "frozen" for the calculation so tuples are probably OK. Can you have produce list rather than tuple however?

Comment: You can use the list() method to convert the tuple into a list. This method can moreover be used on lists(obviously), tuples, sets and dictionaries(where it returns a list of keys)

Comment: to close the question. Tested a master list with 200,000 elements. using list comprehension syntax,  creating 8 lists in (3 x 2 lists 1-go and 3 lists in 1-go takes 1.113seconds. Creating 8 lists one a time takes 0.771 seconds